# Notifications/Invite cap on facebook applications

Tags: facebook

What is the notification/invite limit for a facebook app in a day or is there any cap at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goto the `diagnostics` tab in you app insights and you'll see at the bottom a table named `Feature Limits`.  The default limit for an application is something like 50 per user, per day and it is recalculated according to user feedback (how many users accept the requests sent,how many blocked your app, etc...).

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, was quite hidden :)

Comment: hehe - not really :P but you'll only look for it when u REALLY need it :P